# Switch button in pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Is it possible to create a switch button with pyqt5?

I'm designing a filtering tool in python using pyqt5. The user is supposed to be able to apply a filter or its complement on some data and even combine filters.

I display possible filters in qtablewidget where the user can choose filters to apply using checkboxes. In each row, checkboxes are exclusives i.e. the user can not select a filter and its complement at the same time.

[image]

But the problem is that once we select a checkbox in a row, we cannot deselect it unless we select its opposite. 
In fact, when the filters are just loaded , all the boxes are unchecked (they are empty in a way) so I can choose which filter to apply but when I want to choose an other filter, one of the boxes of the precedent filter still checked (either box Filter or box Complement is checked) and I can not switch it off.

That's why I thought about adding a switch button in each row to disable a filter. By doing this I will be able to take in consideration or not the *checked* attribute.

Here is an example of what I want :

[image]

Below an reproductible example

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(550, 350)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(550, 350))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(550, 350))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 500, 200))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.pushButton_Save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 250, 100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Save.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Save.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Save.setObjectName("pushButton_Save")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 550, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Filter"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "complement"))
        self.pushButton_Save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_Save.clicked.connect(self.bindSave)

    def bindSave(self):
        numRows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(numRows)

        groupButton = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.tableWidget)
        groupButton.setExclusive(True)
        it1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("filter "+str(numRows))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(numRows, 0, it1)
        ch_bx1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        groupButton.addButton(ch_bx1)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(numRows, 1, ch_bx1)
        ch_bx2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        groupButton.addButton(ch_bx2)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(numRows, 2, ch_bx2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui        = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
```

Comment: Is the only issue the deselecting of a set of checkboxes?  If so you could alter that event such that if selected then you programmatically deselect it.

Comment: You can provide an [MRE], maybe my MWE does not match yours so maybe that's the confusion.

Comment: Okay from what it sounds like your checkboxes are working like radio buttons and once one is selected one of them always stays selected.  To deselect them both you would need to catch that via code and turn them off --OR-- you could create a third column with a checkbox and assign it a "No-Filter" state

Comment: @DennisJensen exactly ! You understand me. Nevertheless, I was wondering if I could do this by adding switch buttons.

Comment: @B.Sarah Just with the explanation of Dennis Jensen I understand what you want, in your initial description you were not talking about a new column. Besides that the image clarifies a lot

Comment: okay to me the K.I.S.S. solution would be to simply add a 3rd check box as that would simply extend the current functionality slightly as opposed to adding an entirely new feature just to toggle the usage of your checkboxes on and off.  Also keep in mind that this new feature would have to be created for each row (as your pic implies) so you would be in essence adding that extra column anyway. Just food for thought

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like others have suggested, you could enable/disable filters by adding a third column to the table and setting each item widget in this column to a  like you did for `ch_box1` and `ch_box2`. You can use slots and signals to manipulate the check buttons (for example enable/disable them depending on the state of the switch).

To create custom switches like in the picture in the OP, you could sub-class `QPushButton` and overriding `paintEvent`, e.g. (note that I've omitted the code that was the same as the code in the reproducable example in the original post)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
import sys

class MySwitch(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        print('init')
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setMinimumWidth(66)
        self.setMinimumHeight(22)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        label = "ON" if self.isChecked() else "OFF"
        bg_color = Qt.green if self.isChecked() else Qt.red

        radius = 10
        width = 32
        center = self.rect().center()

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.translate(center)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0))

        pen = QtGui.QPen(Qt.black)
        pen.setWidth(2)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        painter.drawRoundedRect(QRect(-width, -radius, 2*width, 2*radius), radius, radius)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(bg_color))
        sw_rect = QRect(-radius, -radius, width + radius, 2*radius)
        if not self.isChecked():
            sw_rect.moveLeft(-width)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(sw_rect, radius, radius)
        painter.drawText(sw_rect, Qt.AlignCenter, label)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ....
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        ....
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        ...

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "status"))

    def bindSave(self):
        ...
        ch_bx3 = MySwitch()
        ch_bx3.setChecked(True)
        ch_bx3.clicked.connect(ch_bx1.setEnabled)
        ch_bx3.clicked.connect(ch_bx2.setEnabled)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(numRows, 3, ch_bx3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui        = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec()
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of example gui]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for.